# Graphs of iterated functions in Weierstrass's approximation theorem

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am preparing a note for Weierstrass's approximation theorem. There I am stuck with the graphs of the iterated functions generated in the process. How do I draw them in `tikz`? Following are my data:

[image]

I need the graphs for n = 5, 15, 25 and 35. I have made the graphs in *Desmos* for your compliance. Please find it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zzzyrxk3ej). Following is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        f(x)    &=  (\sin x)(\sin \pi x), &&    0\le x\le 1\\[1ex]
        Q_n(x)  &=  \frac{(1-x^{2})^{n}}{\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^{2})^{n}\,dt}, &&    -1\le x\le 1\\[1ex]
        P_n(x)  &=  \int_{0}^{1}f(t)Q_{n}(t-x)dt, &&    0\le x\le 1.
    \end{align*}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=10, yscale=2]
        \draw (-0.05,0) -- (1.1,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);
        \draw [ultra thin, domain=0:1,samples=5000] plot (\x, {sin(\x r)*sin(pi*\x r)});
        \draw (0,1) node[left] {\scriptsize$ (0,1) $} (0,-1) node[left] {\scriptsize$ (0,-1) $};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of functions, the very least you could do is to post copyable versions of the functions. The screen shots do not even agree with the link, `Q_n` has a numerator `\int_{-1}^1(1-t^2)^n\,\mathrm{d}t` (note the `^n`). And you cannot do numerical integration easily with LaTeX, so I am not sure if this is a good idea anyway.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, I am extremely sorry for the mistake. I am editing my question with an MWE.

Comment: This leaves us with the problem that one cannot do numerical integrations so it will be extremely hard to do that with LaTeX only.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, can we approximate using Riemann sum? Suppose we divide the interval `[0,1]` into 500 subintervals. For each `x` from 0 to 500 plot the area of `f(t)Q_{n}(t-x)` using Riemann sum subdividing `[0,1]` into say 10 subintervals? Total number of calculation will be 5000 in that case.

Comment: Yes, something like that. As I said, extremely hard, and not very accurate. So it is doable in principle, with a large amount of computation time and coding efforts, and shaky results. I'd rather create the data with Mathematica, say, and plot it with `pgfplots` if you need a LaTeX plot here.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I do not mind at all. That will also be extremely helpful. I only need the output in my book and not the codes.