# How can I draw graphs of P_n(x) function?

Tags: asymptote

[Graphs of iterated functions in Weierstrass's approximation theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546711/213378)

I have a problem while drawing the following functions:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import graph;
size(8cm,6cm,false);

real F(real x){return sin(x)*sin(pi*x);}

typedef real integral(real);

integral G(int n){return new real(real x){
                            return ((1-x^2)^n)/(simpson(new real(real t){return (1-t^2)^n;},-1,1));}; }

integral Pnx(int n){return new real(real x){ // I think it is right!
                            return simpson(new real(real t){return F(t)*G(n)(t-x);},0,1);}; }

draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),(-2,0)--(2,0),Arrow);
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),(0,-2)--(0,4),Arrow);
int smooth=400;
path f=graph(F,0,1,smooth);
draw(f,brown);

pen pe[]={red,green,blue,cyan,magenta,pink,gray};
pe.cyclic=true;
path g;
for (int i : new int[]{5,10,15,20,25,30,35}){
g=graph(G(i),-1,1,smooth);
draw(g,pe[i]);
}

// path h=graph(Pnx(5),0,1,smooth); // can't draw
// draw(h,blue); // can't draw
```

The output:

[image: cbcb]

Question:

Is my computer weak to draw this function?

Comment: Pure asymptote questions are off topic here, please ask this question on a web page handling asymptote ...

Comment: @Mensch: Please, not again. Your opinion is wrong and insulting,
Pure asymptote questions are on topic here.

Questions tagged [asymptote]

Asymptote is a TeX-aware vector graphics language with built-in 3D capabilities. This tag, which is compatible with the [diagrams] tag, may be used for questions about drawing diagrams. It is also appropriate for questions about the asymptote package, which allows Asymptote code to be included directly in .tex files. 

And anybody are free to answer to such questions 
using alternative drawing tools, like for example,
`metapost` or `pstricks`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import math;
import graph;
size(8cm,6cm,false);
real sc=0.05;
add(shift(-3*sc,-2*sc)*scale(sc)*grid(24,13,paleblue+0.2bp));
real xmin=0,xmax=1;
real ymin=0,ymax=0.5;
xaxis(xmin,xmax,RightTicks(Step=0.2,step=0.1),above=true);
yaxis(ymin,ymax,LeftTicks (Step=0.1,step=0.05),above=true);

real F(real x){return sin(x)*sin(pi*x);}
typedef real realFreal(real);
real sqrtPi=sqrt(pi);
realFreal Q(int n){ // int((1-t^2)^n,t=-1..1)
                    //   = sqrt(pi)*gamma(n+1)/gamma(n+3/2) 
  return 
    new real(real x){
      return (1-x^2)^n*gamma(n+3/2)/gamma(n+1)/sqrtPi;
    }; 
}
realFreal FPn(int n, real x){
  real c=gamma(n+3/2)/gamma(n+1)/sqrt(pi);
  return new real(real t){return c*sin(t)*sin(pi*t)*(1-(t-x)^2)^n;};
}
realFreal Pn(int n){
  return new real(real x){return simpson(FPn(n,x),0,1);};
}

int smooth=400;
pen pe[]={red,green,blue,cyan,magenta,pink,gray}; pe.cyclic=true;

path g;
for (int ni : new int[]{5,10,15,20,25,30,35}){
  g=graph(Pn(ni),0,1,smooth);
  draw(g,pe[ni]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we need `change expression` ?

Comment: @user213378: Integral in the denominator of `Qn(x)`
has an explicit solution, we don't need to use 
`simpson` to solve it numerically.

Comment: I wish I had these représentations of these polynoms when I was a student!

Comment: @g.kov You can read [it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556895/213378). Thanks for `texpath` from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/53f26daba4/).

Comment: @g.kov You can tell me know the mathematical knowledge of this transformation? What is it? `int((1-t^2)^n,t=-1..1)= sqrt(pi)*gamma(n+1)/gamma(n+3/2)`. This is the first time I have seen it. :-(

Comment: @user213378: It's just a known definite integral, see
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28%281-t%5E2%29%5En%2Ct%3D-1..1%29).